# Display all current URL's in yii project

Tags: php, yii

I have inherited a PHP YII project and I'm trying to figure out what it has and does. I was wondering if it's possible to display all URLs that the project routes to.

Examples would be

```
index.php
<controller.php>/index
<controller.php>/search
<controller.php>/add
```

For all controllers and all views.

Comment: This can help you get all actions and cotrollers: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/metadata/

Comment: You could turn logging on and check the logs, I guess?

Comment: @PeterM That's close to what I'm looking for. I guess I was hoping more for a way to see what controllers use what views as well as all potential actions.

Comment: With views it will be harder, as any action can render any view and also view can contain references (partials) to other views :)

Comment: Yeah, I realize this which is why I was hoping for an easy solution. I guess my real question is are there any tools which visualize all potential code paths in  a YII project.

Answer (score 0):

You must look to configs of `UrlManager`/`rules`. Here describes all rules for process requests. Than you will know what controllers and modules (even their actions) are using. Another way I don't know

Comment: Sadly YII allows for controllers to hard code URLs, there's 48 controllers in this project and some of them contain hard coded URLs. I was looking for an easy way to find all URL paths for this project. It's looking like I'll just have to read the entire code base. =P